# Colonizing Mars with Crops

Tags: realism, the-martian

In *The Martian*, after Mark Watney reestablishes contact with Earth, he says this:

> I’ve gotten e-mail from rock stars, athletes, actors and actresses,
> and even the President.
>
> One of them was from my alma mater, the University of Chicago. **They
> say once you grow crops somewhere, you have officially “colonized” it.
> So technically, I colonized Mars.**
>
> In your face , Neil Armstrong!

Is there any evidence that this is true, either from those involved with the movie, those involved with the university, or any other article/source out there?

*If this should be migrated to a different SE, by all means, point the way.*

Comment: The university? You know, there was no Mark Whatney ever enrolled at the University of Chicago (let alone sent to Mars), so I doubt they ever said something like this. I mean, I get you're asking if that statement is an accepted definition, but I don't see what the university has to do with that.

Comment: Another possible interpretation of that sentence is that they (the university) said this *in their email to him.* Which doesn't necessarily mean they (or anyone) said it *before.*

Comment: @Steve-O Oh, I thought that was the only interpretation. I didn't consider that the asker thought they said it at some totally different point.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Yeah, I'm fully aware. But the events being fictional events wouldn't stop the Uni from tweeting something like "This is true! Here's a link to learn more" in the midst of the hubbub over the movie. Barring that, yeah, I was just looking for any tidbit of out-of-universe data supporting the assertion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this stems from the origin of the word "colonise" rather than any legal definition or opinion from any University.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonization#Lexicology)

> The term colonization is derived from the Latin words colere **("to cultivate, to till")**, colonia ("a landed estate", "a farm") and colonus **("a tiller of the soil", "a farmer")**, then by extension "to inhabit". Someone who engages in colonization, i.e. the agent noun, is referred to as a colonizer, while the person who gets colonized, i.e. the object of the agent noun or absolutive, is referred to as a colonizee, colonisee or the colonised.